# Using Dijkstra algorithm with postgreSQL in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-11.10, dijkstra

I am learning PostgreSQL.
I am trying to use Dijkstra algorithm after installing pgrouting to Ubuntu 11.10.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shortest_path(sql text, source_id integer,
       target_id integer, directed boolean, has_reverse_cost boolean)
RETURNS SETOF path_result AS
  '$libdir/libdijkstra.dll'
LANGUAGE 'C' IMMUTABLE STRICT
```

> ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/libdijkstra.dll": No such file
>   or directory'

Please if possible guide me step by step to use it from installation to use.

Comment: Obviously the required library `libdijkstra.dll` is not present in your library directory. You need to install that on your server first, before you can create the PostgreSQL `CREATE FUNCTION` script. I am not familiar with the library, though.

Comment: Additionally to what Erwin already commented, I'd wonder about the name of your shared library. The ending ".dll" is standard for Windows, on Linux it should be ".so"

Comment: can you please tell me, From where I can download library for ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, this is caused by trying to use the Windows library on Linux.  Download a new version at http://pgrouting.org/download.html and use the libraries there, or build from source (available at the same site).